# HTMLAgilityPack and separating on <br/>

Tags: html-agility-pack

I have some html, which is separated by `<br/>` e.g.:

```
Jack Janson
<br/>
309 123 456
<br/>
My Special Street 43
```

What is the easiest way to retrieve the information in 3 columns?

I am not an XPath expert, so another approach would be to separate the string on the line break, and just work with the array. Is there a smarter way to do it?

Update: Forgot to format the code.

Comment: Please post an example of the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure XPATH over XML, you would use an XPATH expression like this: `//preceding-sibling::br` or `//following-sibling::br` (see here for help on [XPATH Axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp%29))

But, the XPATH over HTML implementation that you'll find in Html Agility Pack does not support pure text node or (Attribute node) in XPATH selection expressions (`//br/text()` or `//br/@blah` do not work for example). Note it works in filters, so, these `//br[text()='blah']` or `//br[@att='blah']` work.

So, back to the question, you need to combine XPATH and code, something like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(myHtmlFile);

foreach (HtmlNode p in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.PreviousSibling.InnerText.Trim());
}
```

That will output

```
Jack Janson
309 123 456
```